# Get all characters after a certain character?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

Let's say I have a list of strings like this:

```
list1 = [
"filename1.txt",
"file2.py",
"fileexample.tiff"
]
```

How would I be able to grab all characters after the '.', if it's not too much to ask, by using "`for i in`" and have them come back in a list, like this: `['.txt','.py','.tiff']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
for i in list1:
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(i)
    print fileExtension
```

second one :

```
[i.split('.')[1] for i in list1]
```

Comment: That second one is exactly what I wanted to see. Thank you.

Comment: @Peaser since it is file better to use os.path.split .

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with filepaths, then you should use the `os.path` module

```
import os.path

list1 = ["filename1.txt","file2.py","fileexample.tiff"]
print [os.path.splitext(f)[1] for f in list1]
```

prints

```
['.txt', '.py', '.tiff']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
map(lambda s:s.rsplit(".",1)[-1],my_list)
```

is probably how I would do it

which just splits from the right side exactly once on a period ... and gets whatever is on the right hand side for each item in the list